# Mutable-immutable class pattern on Java depending on package

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, immutability, mutable

Is there any pattern in java that makes a class mutable inside a package and immutable outside of it?

Comment: Note that some of the benefits of immutable objects come from the fact that they are *absolutely* immutable and you will lose them. As an alternative you could have a single interface with a public (fully immutable) implementation and a package-private non-immutable implementation.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of mutable/immutable concept. It has nothing to do with an access modifier. It all about the implementation of that class. Even `ArrayList` and `StringBuilder` has an immutable buffer that will resize itself when needed. Are these two classes immutable? Does adding `final` keyword make them immutable? Is `String` without `final` mutable?

Answer (score 2):

Simply refrain from using any access modifier on all the fields and on those methods that modify the fields, e.g. `String secret;` or `void setSecret(String secret) { ... }`. A field/method that does not have an access modifier is [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which means that it can only be seen by code that resides in the same package.

However, as @JoachimSauer and @Darkman point out, such a class is not in fact *immutable*. Immutable means that an instance will never change (no matter by whom) after it has been constructed. The class will simply be *encapsulated*: only a limited part of your codebase (the package where the class is defined) may modify instances of the class.